# fullcalender last day of week has wrong width

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-1

I am using FullCalendar v1.6.4 and I have problems with events that last for several days and that go over Sunday. The event on Sunday always has the wrong width. In my example I add a event like this:

```
var eventObject = {
                    title: event_text,
                    start: f,
                    end: u,
                    id: 1,
                    color: bgcolor,
                    textColor: "#fff"
                    };
```

Start is 2021/03/21 and end is 2021/03/22. So two days. Sonnday until Monday.

[image]

The event on Sonday gets a width of 11px instead of 156px like all other events:

```
<div class="fc-event fc-event-hori fc-event-start" style="position: absolute; left: 951px; background-color: rgb(0, 204, 0); border-color: rgb(0, 204, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 11px; top: 334px;"><div class="fc-event-inner"><span class="fc-event-title">NEW EVENT</span></div></div>
```

Bests,
Yanick

Comment: Judging by the screenshot, it seems like you have maybe changed the CSS of the theme? Put it back to the default theme and see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: P.S. Fullcalendar 1.x is very old and has not been updated for a long time. Therefore it's also possible there are issues in newer browser versions or something. It's way past the time for you to upgrade to a newer version of fullCalendar. It's on version 5.x now. There are tons of new features, bug fixes, updates etc.